# How to set some using statements as not redundant even if they are?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper, settings, using-statement

Often files when created start with a set of using statements that are common. Sometimes even after fleshing out the class I have no need of a few of the auto-generated using statements. However, removing them can cause problems if they are eventually needed, such as the problems caused by removing using System.Linq;
Is there a way to tell Visual Studio / Resharper not to complain that certain using statements are redundant?

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; // Don't need but want anyway without an error
using System.Linq; // Don't need but want anyway without an error
using System.Net;
using System.Text; // Don't need but want anyway without an error
using Acceptance.EndToEnd.Helpers;
using Acceptance.EndToEnd.Locators;
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, if you leave them. You don't get any errors, do you? I don't use ReSharper but as of VS2015 it just tells you the usings that are not needed. But if you ignore VS2015, you don't run into any problems.

Comment: it'll still compile, and if they are not used they aren't loaded, so there's no performance cost, so why do you care?

Comment: I understand OP, because I like to clean my code up and remove unused statements too. Especially in my test projects (where I experiment with different code snippets): there are classes with identical names in different namespaces in the .NET framework (e.g Windows.Forms vs. WPF). If I would leave all `using` statements I ever needed in my file, I sometimes would use the wrong class and realize it too late. This indeed happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReSharper offers a much better way to do this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might as well remove them, but as has been pointed out, leaving them in does no harm.

If you do remove them, Visual Studio/ReSharper will add them back in as needed - even System.Linq if you use ReSharper.

If you really want, you can stop ReSharper complaining by turning off this warning when you click on the lightbulb:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use ChrisF's answer or you could add ReSharper comments to disable the warnings in your code.

Use

```
// ReSharper disable RedundantUsingDirective
```

at the beginning of the file to disable the warnings in the whole file or use

```
// ReSharper disable once RedundantUsingDirective
using Namespace.That.I.Dont.Need
```

to disable warnings for single `using` statements or use

```
// ReSharper disable RedundantUsingDirective
using Namespace.That.I.Dont.Need
using Another.Namespace.That.I.Dont.Need
// ReSharper restore RedundantUsingDirective
using Namespace.That.I.Do.Need
```

for multiple namespaces.